# What is the meaning of CV_WRAP and CV_OUT on OpenCV Feature2D class

Tags: c++, opencv

Most of the methods contained in the Features2D class report the following symbols: **CV_WRAP** and **CV_OUT**, like in the following:

```
/** Detects keypoints and computes the descriptors */
CV_WRAP virtual void detectAndCompute( InputArray image, InputArray mask,
                                       CV_OUT std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
                                       OutputArray descriptors, bool useProvidedKeypoints=false );
```

What is the meaning of these symbols? On the manual of OpenCV concerning **Utility and system functions and macros** they are defined but they don't have a value associated. Please see here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga4e999bc21cb894d3ed789f3f0bc26778

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those macros are annotations for the [Python wrapper generator](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/python/src2/hdr_parser.py).

For example:

- `CV_WRAP` means that a wrapper should be generated for this function.
- `CV_WRAP_AS` as above, but using the specified alias name (usually for overloads that can't be automatically resolved)
- `CV_OUT` marks an output parameter.
- `CV_IN_OUT` marks an input/output parameter.